# Find two local minima

Tags: python

I have a list of t values. My code for finding the minima values is as follows;

```
for i in np.arange(0,499,1):
    if t[i]<t[i-1] and t[i]<t[i+1] :                       
        t_min.append(t[i])
```

My t values change every time and hence it may happen that one of the minima occurs at the beginning or end in that case this code would not work. So I need a general code which will work for any range of t values.

Comment: What did you try to deal with this corner cases?

Comment: The t values are obtained from a range of phi values which goes from 0 to 2pi. So the case is typically of a circle. In certain situations there could be two minima while in other situations there could be just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop around the end using the % operator and adding one to the length of the iterator. This treats your array 'as a circle', which is what you really want.

```
t_min = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    if  t[i] < min(t[i - 1], t[(i + 1) % len(t)]):
        t_min.append(t[i])
```

Edit: Fix the range of values i takes so that the first element isn't checked twice, thanks to @Jasper for pointing this out

Comment: This seems alright, could you explain this further? Also I think you shouldn't use `t[ i% len(t)]` in the condition because this way you check the zeroth element twice, right?

Comment: Sure! For i=1,...,len(t)-1, you are checking the elements that aren't at either end. For i=0, t[i-1]=t[-1] fetches the last element of the array so you are checking the first element. For i=len(t), i % len(t) = 0, so you have looped back round and got the first element, while checking for the last.
You're right that I didn't need len(t)+1, thanks @Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the array, I suggest using [scipy.signal.argrelmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmin.html#scipy.signal.argrelmin) which finds all local minima. You can pick two you like most from those.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmin
import numpy as np
t = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 500))
relmin = argrelmin(t)[0]
print(relmin)
```

This outputs `[187 437]`.

To treat the array as wrapping around, use `argrelmin(t, mode=‘wrap’)`

---

Without wrap-around, argrelmin does not recognize the beginning and end of an array as candidates for local minimum. (There are different interpretations of "local minimum": one allows the endpoints, the other does not.) If you want the endpoints to be included when the function achieves minimum there, do it like this:

```
if t[0] < t[1]:
    relmin = np.append(relmin, 0)
if t[-1] < t[-2]:
    relmin = np.append(relmin, len(t)-1)
```

Now the output is `[187 437 0]`.